# Message: Trying to get property 'id' of non-object

Tags: php, authentication, notice

I am facing login error. The admin is able to login but when users try to login this error occurs.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LbCDp.png)

My code looks like this

```
   $data = array(

            '_admin_id'         => $query->id,

            '_admin_name'       => $query->name,

            '_admin_email'      => $query->email,

            '_admin_loggedin'   => TRUE,

            '_admin_status'     => $query->status

        );

        $this->session->set_userdata($data);
```

Thanks!

Comment: that's mean your `$query` not containing any value

Comment: Check if your `$query` is object type. If it's array type then access `$query['id']`

Comment: I did that and now receiving Notice error for name, email and status lines. Also now even the admin can't login.